# mongoose search text in nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

there is a nested mongodb document that looks like the image below. I want to do a search in the body field in this document, but I could not succeed. how can i do this search. thanks in advance

[image: Image of my document]

I tried to search like this. Is my path correct?

```
const result = await this.campaignModel.find({
       "sequencesPageData": {
         "$elemMatch": {
           "mailSteps": {
             "$elemMatch": {
               "mailTemplate": x
             }
           }
         }
       }
     });
```

I did a search like this but got no results.

```
const result = await this.campaignModel.find({
       "sequencesPageData": {
         "$elemMatch": {
           "mailSteps": {
             "$elemMatch": {
               "mailTemplate": x
             }
           }
         }
       }
     });
```

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only testing a single field in the array, there is no need to use $elemMatch, you can use dot notation:

```
db.collection.find({ "sequencesPageData.mailSteps.mailTemplate.body": "x" })
```

$elemMatch is useful to ensure that 2 or more tests are satisfied by the same array element, but since this example uses only 1 test, it works without.

Comment: it worked correctly in this answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For object fields, simply access them using dot notation. For array fields, use `$elemMatch` to perform the match.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "sequencesPageData.mailSteps": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "mailTemplate": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "subject": "asdf"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hT8wve587so)